# Build directory for ./configure?

Tags: configure, conventions, autoconf

Recently, I compiled gdb by using `configure` and `make`. To guarantee that the code was built into another directory (`build`), I executed the `configure` script from the build directory. (with `../binutils/configure`)

Is this strategy (executing configure from within the wished build directory to specify the build directory) written down in some standard, a written convention or similar or does there not exist such a common practice?

Comment: Any mature build system based on autotools should be capable of building out-of-tree. automake provides variables like `$top_srcdir`, `$srcdir`, and `$top_builddir`.

Comment: I

Not sure where exactly it is documented, but it is a supported convention for sure. E.g. `make distcheck`

Answer (score 0):

It is e.g. documented here:

> The GNU Build System distinguishes two trees: the source tree, and the
> build tree. These are two directories that may be the same, or
> different.

https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/VPATH-Builds.html

E.g. the `make distcheck` makes use of this when doing its test build, and makes the source directory read-only so that any misconfigured build rule that creates files in the srcdir instead of builddir gets reported as an error during that check:

https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Checking-the-Distribution.html

So while autotools may not advertise this differentiation of source and build directories as strongly as Cmake does it actually has *stronger* support for it as Cmake is missing such a check feature.